# Trying to join two datasets via csv and python

Tags: python, csv

I currently have two csv files full of objects. The objects in one of the csv files contains an object id, and various other info fields. The other contains the object id's that reference to the first file along with other info about the objects.

I'm trying to output a third csv file that contains all of the information for each object. Looping through these traditionally is too slow as there are ~3 million objects in one of the files. Does there exist a python package or other solution that makes this process more efficient?

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). it is pretty good with CSV files especially if you have special characters etc. For larger files, you can read files in by chunk, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: This shell oneliner ought to do it: `join -j1 -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv)` (assuming we're joining on first field in both files and comma is used to separate fields).

Comment: @randomir how would I change that if I'm not joining on first field?

Comment: @PatrickConnors you would have to sort each individual file in bash first, as such `sort file1.csv -t, -k1,1 > file1.csv.sorted`, you can replace the ints after k with whatever column you need to sort

Comment: @PatrickConnors, with `-1` and `-2`: `join -1 2 -2 3 -t, <(sort -t, -k2 file1.csv) <(sort -t, -k3 file2.csv)`. In this case you must sort the files on the respective field (2 for file1 and 3 for file2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only requires that data from the smaller csv file be kept in memory.

```
import csv

extra_data {}
with open('smaller.csv', newline='') as fin1:
    reader = csv.reader(fin1)
    for row in reader:
        objid = row[0] # or whichever field has the object id
        extra_data[objid] = row[1:]

with open('bigger.csv', newline='') as fin2, open('combined.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin2)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
        objid = row[0] # or whichever field has the object id
        new_row = row + extra_data.get(objid, [])
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```